# How to Deserialize Json string to Type without creating class

Tags: c#, json

I have an Json string.I would like to know how to Deserialize "Type" from Json string "without creating class".Please check my below code and advise how to do this....

```
string MParam = @"[{'ColCode': 'BK'}]";
object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MParam);
```

Comment: Let's say you do this, but what purpose does this solve? Aren't you assuming that JSON structure will never change at least for the fields you will hard code.

Comment: you can also use anonymous class

Comment: What is `"Type"` and what does `"without creating class"` mean? Don't make us guess. JSON is parsed by its interpreter into objects that apply to that particular language. "Type" could be an array, a hash, or the derivations for that language, and the class will be whatever the language calls it. Arrays and Hashes... whatever, we still need more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

you can use 'dynamic' type

```
        string MParam = @"[{'ColCode': 'BK'}]";
        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(MParam);
        var ColCode = result[0].ColCode;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....How can I get "ColCode" and "BK" from dynamic ???

Comment: you can get ColCode value like this: var ColCode = result[0].ColCode

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this, i have done two way for this, but i would like to use second one.

```
string MParam = @"[{'ColCode': 'BK'}]";
var jsonArray = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MParam);
var jo = (JObject)jsonArray[0];
Console.WriteLine(jo["ColCode"]);
```

and this next way is useful in many other places too, which uses anonymous

```
string MParam = @"[{'ColCode': 'BK'}]";
var colCodeDef = new[] { new { ColCode = "" } };
var myType = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(MParam, colCodeDef);
var ColCodeData = myType[0].ColCode;
```

Comment: We can use JArray and JObject but we will lose the static type name intellisense when we use them. So, I would prefer using anonymous class which can be declared anywhere we need without creating a class template file.

Comment: yes @SurendraShrestha so i added  an example of anonymous type too.. Thank you for your suggestion